# Preloader for loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I am currently working on SVG SMIL animation in which I am using some .png and .gif files for easing my animation in IE. For this animation I am trying to get Preloader before animation and its other contents get loaded.

Problem is I am not getting that Preloader working properly. My .html page is getting loaded first and then preloader is starting... In Preloader also, I have used several preloaders available on the web. But they are not helpful for me.

Script and .html files loading time can be counted by domContentLoaded but for images. I dont know how to do that. If someone can suggest me a way that would be great.

here is code of preloader.js, I found on web:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict"
//indexOf support for IE8 and below. 
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf){
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/){
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++){
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}

//bgImg for holding background images in the page & img array for images present in the document(<img src="">).
var bgImg = [], img = [], count=0, percentage = 0;

//Creating loader holder. 
$('<div id="loaderMask"><span>0%</span></div>').css({
    position:"fixed",
    top:0,
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
    right:0,
    background:'#fff'
}).appendTo('body');

//Using jQuery filter method we parse all elemnts in the page and adds background image url & images src into respective arrays.
$('*').filter(function() {

    var val = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\(/g,'').replace(/\)/,'').replace(/"/g,'');
    var imgVal = $(this).not('image').attr('xlink:href');

    //Getting urls of background images.
    if(val !== 'none' && !/linear-gradient/g.test(val) && bgImg.indexOf(val) === -1){
        bgImg.push(val)
    }

    //Getting src of images in the document.
    if(imgVal !== undefined && img.indexOf(imgVal) === -1){
        img.push(imgVal)
    }
});

//Merging both bg image array & img src array
var imgArray = bgImg.concat(img); 
console.log(imgArray.length);
//Adding events for all the images in the array.
$.each(imgArray, function(i,val){ 
    //Attaching load event 
    $("<image />").attr("xlink:href", val).bind("load", function () {
        console.log('val'+val);
        completeImageLoading();
    });

    //Attaching error event
    $("<image />").attr("xlink:href", val).bind("error", function () {
        imgError(this);
    });
})

//After each successful image load we will create percentage.
function completeImageLoading(){
    count++;
    percentage = Math.floor(count / imgArray.length * 100);
    console.log('percentage:'+percentage);
    $('#loaderMask').html('<span>'+percentage + '%'+'</span>');

    //When percentage is 100 we will remove loader and display page.
    if(percentage == 100){
        $('#loaderMask').html('<span>100%</span>')
        $('#loaderMask').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#loaderMask').remove()
        })
    }
}

//Error handling - When image fails to load we will remove the mask & shows the page. 
function imgError (arg) {
    $('#loaderMask').html("Image failed to load.. Loader quitting..").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#loaderMask').remove();
    })
}
```

});

Comment: have you tried any code yet, if yes than please share.

Comment: I have used preloader.js, which I found on web. I am updating my code with that javascript

Comment: problem is in svg <image> tag's source is given by 'xlink:href' not 'src'. and in this when I try to bind 'xlink:href' its going direcly to  error function

Answer (score 1):

A little trick I do to ensure my or external data  or images are loaded before I start executing my js code is, I create a div with display:none and fill it with all the tags that I need loaded.

```
<body>

    <span id="loadingText">Loading...</span>

    <div style="display:none">
        <img src="pathtoimage1">
        <img src="pathtoimage2">
        <img src="pathtoimage3">
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
           //This gets called when all the items in that div has been loaded and cached.
           document.getElementById("loadingText").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: thats not bad but my code allows the page to load at the same time so there is little delay in page loading because the css loads first.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for preloading images for animations.
you can add and remove how many you load as needed.

```
<script language="javascript">function preloader() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();
        var img4 = new Image();
        var img5 = new Image();
        var img6 = new Image();
        var img7 = new Image();
        var img8 = new Image();
        var img9 = new Image();

        img1.src = "image link here";
        img2.src = "image link here";
        img3.src = "image link here";
        img4.src = "image link here";
        img5.src = "image link here";
        img6.src = "image link here";
        img7.src = "image link here";
        img8.src = "image link here";
        img9.src = "image link here";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);</script>
```